# Semantic-UI-React transitions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, semantic-ui-react

Essentially i'd like to have this `Success Message` component render with a transition when the state changes.

I followed the [docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/transition/#types-transition), but I'm still missing something integral (duh!)

This is my component:

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: true,
      isVisible: false,
      hide: 1000,
      show: 1000,
      username: '',
      password: '',
      usernameError: false,
      passwordError: false,
      formError: true,
      formSuccess: false
    }

//methods:

 this.toggleVisibility = this.toggleVisibility.bind(this)
 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
 this.handleIsLoggedInClick = this.handleIsLoggedInClick.bind(this)
 this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}
```

The function which I created for toggling visibility:

```
toggleVisibility () { this.setState({ isVisible: !this.state.isVisible })}
```

And the component that toggles:

```
{(!formError && formSuccess) ?
  <Transition visible={()=>{this.toggleVisibility}} animation='scale' duration={500}>
    <Message success header='Your user registration was successful' content='You may now log-in with the username you have chosen' />
  </Transition>
: null
}
```

Now won't this just fire when the component becomes visibile from the 
`(!formError && formSuccess) ?`

```
visible={()=>{this.toggleVisibility}}
```

**UPDATE**

I guess I should have supplied a visual:
To clarify—I'd when a user successfully enters the correct info to sign up, the success component simply animates into the DOM with the same transition found [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/transition/#explorers-group-explorer)

That example show the results achieved with a button firing it off.
I'd like it to be the form being successfully filled out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visible={()=>{this.toggleVisibility}}` should be `visible={this.toggleVisibility}`

I believe the way you have it you are currently you are running a function with a return of `undefined`.

Also, but I don't think the function gets to run again when `this.toggleVisibility` gets updated. If it does run again your function should look like `visible={()=>this.toggleVisibility}` and  `visible` inside the component would have to be called as a function `props.visible()` however, a function is not required to get the desired effect.

edit: changed null to undefined

Edit 2: here is an example https://codesandbox.io/embed/yp1p7vo3q1?fontsize=14 I did use hooks, but its more or less the same

Edit 3: `toggleVisibility` does not need to exist

```
{(!formError && formSuccess) ?
  <Transition visible={()=>{this.toggleVisibility}} animation='scale' duration={500}>
    <Message success header='Your user registration was successful' content='You may now log-in with the username you have chosen' />
  </Transition>
: null
}
```

should be

```
 <Transition visible={(!this.formError && this.formSuccess)} animation='scale' duration={500}>
    <Message success header='Your user registration was successful' content='You may now log-in with the username you have chosen' />
  </Transition>
```

Comment: The return value of the arrow function set for the `visible` prop is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for that! but I believe I wasn't clear—I don't want a button to trigger the transition I'd like a condition to facilitate it. In my case the form Component being filled out successfully.

Comment: Thanks my friend this did it!